# identity involving arithmetic function

Tags: number-theory

I have a question concerning the identity below.  I am having difficulty proving it without the use of induction.  In particular, I am not sure how to deal with the floor of n on the index of summations on the right hand side.  If someone can explain it to me or give me suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\tau(j)=2\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor{\sqrt n}\rfloor}\lfloor\frac{n}{j}\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt n\rfloor}^{2}$

Comment: Well, I guess you mean $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\tau(j)=2\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{j}\right\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt n\rfloor}^{2},$$ and you should define $\tau$, because notations differ widely in number theory ($d(n)$ or $\sigma_0(n)$ are other frequent variants instead of $\tau(n)$). BTW, the "without using induction" is even more ludicrous in this context; it would be a real challenge to prove it **with** induction.

Comment: @Professor Vector, thank you for the response.  I want to know how to do it without induction because I want to know how the identity was derived.  If I can do it without induction, then I would know where it came from.  Thanks

Comment: I've told you you **can't** prove it with induction, even if you tried. One method to derive it would be [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m105f13/public_html/m105f13notes2.pdf), though you'd need one more step from the last line of page 1.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, sorry I thought you meant it will be difficult doing it without induction.  The question came from Kenneth Rosen's Elementary Number Theory text.  The solution given there uses an induction proof.  By the way, is there a general method of dealing with floor or ceiling function when it appears in index of summations.   Thank you.

Comment: Both the LHS and the RHS count the number of lattice points in the first quadrant, below the hyperbola $xy=n$. Have a look at Terence Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dirichlet-hyperbola-method/) about Dirichlet's hyperbola method.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, thank you for the reference.